# Using imageJ plugin from jython : how to call it in the script?

Tags: plugins, jython, imagej

I want to use Jython to analyse images on ImageJ, but I don't know how to call existing plugins and run it from the script. Do you have an idea ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the syntax `from packagename import namespace`

An example:

```py
from ij import IJ, ImagePlus
from ij.plugin.filter import RankFilters

imp = IJ.getImage()
ip = imp.getProcessor().convertToFloat()

radius = 2
RankFilters().rank(ip, radius, RankFilters.MEDIAN)

imp2 = ImagePlus(imp.title + " median filtered", ip)
imp2.show()
```

You can find the name of specific plugins by searching the command finder.

Comment: I want to add lines on the image with the plugin OverlayCommands but I don't know how to run it correctly, I show you the code :                                                             
from ij import IJ, ImagePlus
from ij.plugin import OverlayCommands as OC

nLines = 5;
width = 877;
height = 649;
tileWidth = width/(nLines+1);
tileHeight = tileWidth;

yoff=tileHeight;
while (True and yoff<height): # draw horizonal lines
     IJ.makeLine(0, yoff, width, yoff);
     OC.run("add");
     yoff = yoff + tileHeight;

Comment: The formatting gets messed up in SO comments. From what I can tell your code is fine, but your syntax is not. Remove the terminating semi-colons, each part on a new line and indent the last three lines in the while loop. It ran for me in Fiji
```from ij import IJ, ImagePlus
from ij.plugin import OverlayCommands as OC

nLines = 5
width = 877
height = 649
tileWidth = width/(nLines+1)
tileHeight = tileWidth
yoff=tileHeight
while (True and yoff<height): # draw horizonal lines
 IJ.makeLine(0, yoff, width, yoff)
 OC.run("add")
 yoff = yoff + tileHeight
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It was in fact a syntax problem.